# Animation not happening when pushing viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am trying to animate a button edit: “while” the view controllers are pushed. However, the button does not animate, the views are pushed properly though.

Here is my code:

```
        createAccountButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
        self.createAccountButton.transform = .identity
        let signUpVC = SignUpViewController()
        //        presentDetail(signUpVC)
        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 0.5
        transition.type = CATransitionType.push
        transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromRight
        transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
        self.view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
        self.present(signUpVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
    })
```

Thanks

Comment: If you want to animate the button before the transition is happening you should place your transition code in the completion block of the animate function.

Comment: I tried and it works but the animation looks off, because the animation occurs and then the controller gets pushed after a second (which is the duration time of the animation).  I want them to occur at the same time.

Comment: if you want both animations overlapping did you have a look at animateKeyframes(withDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:) ? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622552-animatekeyframes

Comment: Still no luck ` UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration:0.5, animations: {() in
                // initial 
            })
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration:0.5, animations: {() in
            })
        })`

Answer (score 0):

You should animate the button in the **animations** block and **present** the next screen in the **completion** block which is executed after the animation ends.

```
createAccountButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
     self.createAccountButton.transform = .identity
  }) { _ in
     let signUpVC = SignUpViewController()
     //        presentDetail(signUpVC)
     let transition = CATransition()
     transition.duration = 0.5
     transition.type = CATransitionType.push
     transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromRight
     transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
     self.view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
     self.present(signUpVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
  }
```

Comment: It does work, however, the animation occurs and then the presentation. So it looks awkward, I wanna of them at the same time if thats possible

Comment: Oh, I see, you said you are trying to animate the button **before** pushing, that's what the above code does.

Comment: The only 2 ways I can think of right now are: 1. Use UIPageViewController and create the button in the UIPageViewController, 2. Add the button to apps keyWindow